# Common if or ternary operator for many actions statement?

Tags: if-statement, ternary-operator

I'm thought about how to do many actions in single ternary statement, but finished with almost the same as the common IF. So which is better, or there is no differences?

```
video[0].muted ? (
    video[0].muted = false,
    vb.attr("data-value", "loud")
) : (
    video[0].muted = true,
    vb.attr("data-value", "off")
);
//
if(video[0].muted) {
    video[0].muted = false;
    vb.attr("data-value", "loud");
} else {
    video[0].muted = true;
    vb.attr("data-value", "off");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice clean way of writing this that uses plain negation and a ternary would be:

```
var v = video[0];

// Negate the muted attribute
v.muted = !v.muted;

// And use a ternary to decide the value of this one
vb.attr("data-value", v.muted ? "off" : "loud");
```

Notice how the ternary is just being used here to decide which String to use.

Don't use ternarys to carry out side effects though. That's not what they're for, and abusing them never helps code readability. If you need side effects (mutating some variable), just use a plain `if`...`else`. They're much more readable.

Comment: +50 for the last statement. People abuse ternarys as if they are "edgier" than `if`s.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides That's a personal pet-peeve of mine for some reason. I get shivers when I see people cramming stuff into ternarys in the name of brevity.